# Is there a way to downscale images so load time isnt massively bogged down

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loading

I'm writing a gallery application that pulls images from an rss feed, so editing the images directly isn't an option.

Unfortunately some of the galleries are quite large because the files were uploaded as a large scale.

Is there a way to make sure when the images are loaded to have them load at a reasonable size with javascript/jquery?

Thanks for your help as always!

Oh also- if im linking these images directly from the rss to the site they originated from, say- a google rss feed, can that land me in any trouble with them loading a bunch of images off their site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just javascript / jquery, no.

Assuming that storing the images on your server isn't an option, you would have to use a server side script like php to load the image on your server, scale it down and deliver that to the browser.

So your client side script would be something like

```
$("#myImgTag").attr( 'src', 'http://yourserver.com/getRSSimage.php?url=google.com/rss/reallyBigImage' );
```

As to the legality of linking directly, its a legal gray area. If you try to state that the images are yours, then yes its illegal, however, clearly showing where the images came from giving all necessarily credit, that's considered ok especially if you're not making money from it.

Comment: oh of course, im just making gallerys to display my picassa web albums on my personal site- so i can mess with the display formating and not have to worry about writing my own image upload stuff and databases

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make sure when the images are loaded to have them
>   load at a reasonable size with javascript/jquery?

No

> if im linking these images directly from the rss to the site they
>   originated from, say- a google rss feed, can that land me in any
>   trouble with them loading a bunch of images off their site?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for would be server-side operation.  jQuery in the client browser can only operate on the images after they have been received in the browser.  To download smaller images, you would need to either:

1) Learn how to request smaller images from the site rather than the larger sizes.  For example, if the RSS feed was from a photo site like Smugmug, the image URLs can be modified to request a smaller size.

2) Modify the server to support a request for a smaller size (I presume this is not an option for you).

Whether what you are doing will get you into trouble depends on more of the details of what you are doing.  A site on the web with public images and a public RSS feed is allowing some fair use of those, but is not allowing unlimited use for any purpose.  We would have to know a lot more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no not really.  even logically, such transformation has to occur somewhere, and you have to do so to the original. That being the case, since you have to load the original anyway, there is no point to re-sizing it.  And as for hotlinking, I don't think it's illegal, but the site that you are hotlinking from will hate you for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the gallery always uses the same RSS feed, you could look into scaling and storing the images on the server. When a user visits your gallery, a simple check could be made for whether the "thumbnail" image is available and to load that one instead. That would require a little JavaScript / AJAX, and you'd have to write some code to scale and store images.

This really isn't ideal though. Scaling and storing images is both processor and memory intensive. If you're serving lots of users and lots of images, this isn't going to scale well. I don't see any problem with you pulling lots of images from a server... that's what they're there for right? Just make sure you're not being wasteful with your requests and respecting the bandwidth of the server.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in that the image optimization would need to be done server-side. There are some tools that can do this work for you, however, which would enable you to serve optimized images just by modifying the image src that you're assigning through JS.

Take a look at http://www.punypng.com/api for an example.

Take note that this isn't ideal, though, since you're relying on the resources/etc of an outside server to serve images.